# Routing with Search Queries in Angular

Tags: angularjs, html, routes

Does anyone know how I can route using a search query in Angular? I have tried working with `$routeProvider` but it doesn't work with search queries.

This is the code I wrote for routing with `$routeProvider`:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider.when('/?table=table1', {
  controller:'PostsCtrl',
  templateUrl: 'table1.html'
}) 
  $routeProvider.when('/?table=table2', {
    controller: 'PostsCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'table2.html' 
})
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/?table=table1'});
}]);

app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider){
   $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
}]);
```

and the templates they are referring to:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="table1.html">
  some code
</script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="table2.html">
  some code
</script>
```

Comment: can you share the code please

Comment: @DebasishMohapatra I'll add the code that I wrote for routing with `$routeProvider`

Comment: You can find this link helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15155911/how-to-pass-querystring-in-angular-routes