# Angular.JS routing to view with appended token URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, view

When a user registers on my new site, they get an email with a link. That links directs the user to site such as:

localhost:9000/#/pwset?token=LMhsb3z94ptqrqZ7I8WBaht3WC1AOjdK9jcOTXz5tOuJRj3olzrS8kspHAOtlE%2Fgijnfok

That said, sometimes the links builds the view fine, other times the header and footer appear, but the view content does not.

Anyone have any ideas of why this would be? My routing is quite simple and set to:

```
$routeProvider.when("/pwset", {
    controller: "signupController",
    templateUrl: "ppt/views/logreg/pwset.html"
});
```

Actually, the routing seem correct in terms of the link you shared. To add, refreshing the link with f5 makes the view render correctly even though it is the same link

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to pass querystring in angular routes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15155911/how-to-pass-querystring-in-angular-routes)

Comment: Actually, the routing seem correct in terms of the link you shared. To add, refreshing the link with f5 makes the view render correctly even though it is the same link.

Comment: any errors thrown? does url stay intact in address bar? Is an ajax request failing due to bad parsing of url? Not much info given about failed state

Comment: No, no errors thrown at all....