# what is the correct way of passing query parameters to controller?

Tags: angularjs

I want to pass some query parameters from html to the controller.  It is not working like I thought it would.   Here is my code.   Basically, I have 3 parameters.  The imei is the path variable, the startdate and enddate are the 
query parameters.

HTML

```
  <td sortable="'imei'" data-title="'IMEI'">
     <a ng-href="#/{{row.imei}}/graph?startDate={{main.startDate}}&
       endDate={{main.endDate}}">{{row.imei}}
     </a>
  </td>
```

RouteProvider code

```
function MainConfig($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/main', {
      templateUrl: 'main/main.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'main'
    })
    .when('/:imei/graph?startDate&endDate', {
      templateUrl: 'graph/graph.html',
      controller: 'GraphCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'graph'
    });
}
```

Controller code

```
function GraphCtrl(Graph, $filter, RcTableParams, moment, $routeParams) {
  var graph = this;
  graph.imei = $routeParams.imei;
  graph.startDate = $routeParams.startDate;
  graph.endDate = $routeParams.endDate;
  . 
  .
}
```

I know the Path Parameter works.  As soon as I added the query parameters, the code stopped working.  Am I specifying the route information correctly ?   Thanks for you time.

Comment: Change to a more RESTful-ish URL.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15155911/how-to-pass-querystring-in-angular-routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the $location service for that

```
function GraphCtrl(Graph, $filter, RcTableParams, moment, $routeParams,$location) {
  var graph = this;
  graph.imei = $routeParams.imei;
  graph.startDate = $location.search().startDate;
  graph.endDate = $location.search().endDate;

  . 
  .
}
```

Comment: The location service did not make any differences.

Comment: and please make it when 
.when('/:imei/graph?startDate&endDate', {

to .when(/:imei/graph',{

and use same $routeParams..or you can also use $location.search()  if you use proper search..

Comment: Thank you.  Getting rid of the ?startDate&endDate seems to do the trick.